# Root partition not growing after LV increase

Tags: linux, lvm

Sorry if this seems stupid, but I'm still kinda new to Linux. So for a class we need to make a VM, I wanted to try and save space on my hard drive, so I only gave it 25 gigs. That's always been more than enough.

This time, I'm running out of space. I figured this would be a great chance to see LVM commands in action. So I add another 40GB hard drive in through VirtualBox and start the machine back up.

Next I format my new sdb with ext4. I then create a PV out of it. I add that PV to my existing VG. Finally, I extend my existing LV with `sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/parrot--vg-root`. It goes through without a problem. If I do a `lvscan` I can see that the LV has over 60.28 GiB.

I'm still getting warnings about my root partition running out of space though. If I run `df -h` I can see that `/dev/mapper/parrot--vg-root` only has 505MB free. If I run `fdisk -l` it shows that `/dev/mapper/parrot--vg-root` should also have over 60GiB. I just don't understand why my root partition isn't growing to reflect this new space.

I've also tried to run `resize2fs /dev/mapper/parrot--vg-root` but I get an error that the "device or resource busy while trying to open...".

There is nothing important on the machine so I could just wipe it and reinstall it with a bigger hard drive this time, but if possible I'd like to learn what I'm doing wrong so in the future I can handle LVM systems better.

Images for reference:

[image] (df -h)

[image] (fdisk -l)

[image] (lvscan)

[image] (resize2fs)

Comment: You are quite close.  What filesystem are you using on /?  It seems that is the only thing you’ve failed to do, resize the filesystem to take advantage of the larger volume.

Comment: It looks like your root filesystem is not ext4. The `blkid` command lists storage devices and the data structures they have on them, including filesystems. Try it. And next time, run `lvextend -r`, since this also resizes the filesystem.

Comment: You guys saying that I was not using ext4 on root lead me to do more digging online. I eventually found it was using btrfs instead. I was able to resize it while it was mounted with "sudo btrfs filesystem resize max /"

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Now execute:

```
$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sda2
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2
```

Comment: No, one should not run a filesystem check on a filesystem that is mounted. And since this is the root filesystem, it cannot be easily unmounted for checking.

Answer (score 1):

So some of the comments lead me to realizing that I wasn't using ext4 for /. I found out I was using btrfs instead. So after some more digging, I found the command to resize it while it was still mounted. It was sudo btrfs filesystem resize max /. Thanks for everyone's input, I would have never figured it out without you!